# How to add fadein to this script with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, fadein

I used fadein from this site http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ what i want to do is display modal slowly(with this fadein effect). But problem is that i donw know where to exactly put this function. I tried probably everything.

```
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;
    last = +new Date();

    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}

fadeIn(el);
```

And my script

```
// Get the modal
var modal'.$post->id.' = document.getElementById("myModal'.$post->id.'");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn'.$post->id.'");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close'.$post->id.'")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal'.$post->id.'.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal'.$post->id.'.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

What i want to do is to add this fade in to this part of code but i dont know how to do it correctly

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal'.$post->id.'.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: You cannot fade in with `display:none` — `display:block`. Only with `opacity`. You want to set a `CSS3` command for that. `transition: all 0.1s linear` on the `element` that fades.

Comment: i added transition to every single class used but it done nothing :/

Comment: It wants to be `modal<?php echo $post->id?>.style.opacity = 1;`. Or what is this `$post->id`?

Comment: This javascript is in my php file becuase i was unable to make make modal box on page items without this probably stupid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this simple library i always use for animation purposes. Simply download animate.min.css from github here https://github.com/daneden/animate.css add it to the head of your page like this:

```
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>
```

And then you can add this to your script like this.

```
$('#yourElement').addClass('animated fadeOut');
```

or

```
modal'.$post->id.'.classList.add('animated fadeOut');
```

I hope this helps?